# Python program - Random word generator

Tags: python, random, cpu-word

Im trying to make a program where it will randomly print one of the two words it can chose from when you hit enter. Here are the question & the anwsers. Its meant to be from the card game 'Smoke or Fire / Higher or lower'

```
sof = raw_input("Smoke or Fire?: ")
print "SMOKE" or "FIRE"

horl = raw_input("Higher or Lower?: ")
print "HIGHER" or "LOWER"

IOO = raw_input ("Inside or Out?: ")
print "INSIDE" or "OUT"

horl = raw_input("Higher or Lower?: ")
print "HIGHER" or "LOWER"

sof = raw_input("Smoke or Fire?: ")
print "SMOKE" or "FIRE"
```

Can anyone help?!?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose what you want to print, randomly.
It's as simple to use as `print random.choice(['SMOKE', 'FIRE'])`.

Comment: perhaps you should say something about `import random` since OP seems somewhat clueless